# Independence of multivariate random vectors

Tags: probability, independence

Assume that $X$  and $Y$ are two independent multivariate random vectors.

So we have that $$P[X_i \leq x_i,X_2 \leq x_2,..., X_p \leq x_p  \text{ and }Y_i \leq y_i,Y_2 \leq y_2,...,Y_q \leq y_q ]=P[X_i \leq x_i,X_2 \leq x_2,..., X_p \leq x_p]  \cdot P[Y_i \leq y_i,Y_2 \leq y_2,...,Y_q \leq y_q].$$

How can I show that each component of X is independent of each component of Y?

*(For $p = q = 1$ it is given, but what if they tend to infinity. A proof by induction could be an idea, but I cannot even figure it out for $p = q = 2$.
)*

Answer (score 0):

For a particular component $X_i$, we may take $x_j \to +\infty$ for $j \neq i$:

$$ \begin{align} 
&\Pr\left\{X_i \leq x_i, \bigcap_{k=1}^n Y_k \leq y_k\right\}\\
=& \Pr\left\{X_i \leq x_i, \bigcap_{{\substack j=1} \\ {j \neq i}}^n X_j \leq +\infty, \bigcap_{k=1}^n Y_k \leq y_k\right\} \\
=& \Pr\left\{X_i \leq x_i, \bigcap_{{\substack j=1} \\ {j \neq i}}^n X_j \leq +\infty \right\} \Pr\left\{\bigcap_{k=1}^n Y_k \leq y_k\right\} \\
=& \Pr\left\{X_i \leq x_i \right\} 
\Pr\left\{\bigcap_{k=1}^n Y_k \leq y_k\right\}\end{align}$$

Here we just use a trivial fact that if $P(A) = 1$, then $P(A \cap B) = P(B)$

Answer (score 0):

If you let $x_2,x_3,...,x_p \to \infty$ and $y_2,y_3,...,y_q \to \infty$ you get $P[X_i \leq x_i, Y_i \leq y_n]=P[X_i \leq x_i] P[Y_i \leq y_i]$. Hence $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent.

Comment: I meant $p, q \to \infty$. How can I show for all i and j that $P[X_i \leq x_i \text{ and }Y_j \leq y_j]=P[X_i \leq x_i] P[Y_j \leq y_j]$ given that X and Y are independent

Comment: @AnnaSchmitz The argument I gave works for any $p$ and $q$.